# How to move the main entry file path to index.json?

Tags: jquery, node.js, sass, node-sass

I'm building a jquery/sass project and I need to export the javascript and the scss file to node.

Using the `main` field in the `package.json` file I can link the main entry point which if the package was only a jquery module, I'd point to the main javascript file `dist/jquery.package.js`

But since I work with node-sass too, I need to export the path to the package too in order to use the sass bindings. To do so, I have to create a `index.js` file in which I have to resolve the path to the package:

`index.js` file would looke like this:

```
var path = require( "path" );

module.exports = {
  includePaths: [
    path.join( __dirname )
  ]
};
```

To make the node-sass bindings works, I have to change the `main` field in the `package.json` file from `dist/jquery.package.js` to `index.js` but by doing so, I would lose the the chace to export my jquery plugin.

Is it possible to move the main entry path `dist/jquery.package.json` inside `index.js` along with the `includePaths` for node-sass option?

How can I do both?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`browser` field at package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#browser). Example:

```
{
  ...
  "main": "index.js",
  "browser": "dist/jquery.package.js",
  ...
}
```